# Wicket: AjaxLazyLoadPanel without extra files

Tags: wicket

I am looking for a way to AJAX lazy load a panel without having to add extra files (e.g. a new Class and .html file). I am familiar with using `AjaxLazyLoadPanel`. The idea would be to quickly wrap a slow loading portion of a page in a lazy load without needing to write a lot of code and without needing to break out markup into separate files. Is there a solution to this that is already available?

**Example:**
I am in a `WebPage` and I want a portion of the page to lazy load. One possible solution might work something like a `wicket:container` tag.

```
<body>
  <h1>The DIV Below Is Lazy</h1>
  <wicket:lazy wicket:id="lazyLoadMe">
    <div wicket:id="slowLoadingRepeater">
      <div wicket:id="item">[stuff goes here]</div>
    </div>
  </wicket:lazy>
  <div wicket:id="loadRightAway"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably looking for **Fragment**.
The following example shows how to add an instance of the AjaxLazyLoadPanel and put a content from the same markup, so far you don't have to create any other class or markup file just to separte the content. The full working example is available at https://stash.twinstone.org/projects/WISTF/repos/wicket-examples-6.x/browse

**AjaxLazyLoadPanelPage (java)**

```
public class AjaxLazyLoadPanelPage extends WebPage {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

/**
 * @param parameters
 */
public AjaxLazyLoadPanelPage(PageParameters parameters) {
    super(parameters);
    add(new AjaxLazyLoadPanel("lazyLoadedPanel") {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public Component getLazyLoadComponent(String componentId) {
            return new Fragment(componentId, "lazyContentFragment", AjaxLazyLoadPanelPage.this)
            .add(new Label("text", Model.of("real content")));
        }
    });
}

}
```

**AjaxLazyLoadPanelPage.html (markup)**

```
<body xmlns:wicket="http://wicket.apache.org">

<div>
    <h1>Ajax Laxy Load Panel Example</h1>
    <div wicket:id="lazyLoadedPanel">This is a lazy loaded panel</div>
</div>

<wicket:fragment wicket:id="lazyContentFragment">
    If you see this content, the lazy laoded panel has been replaced with its <span wicket:id="text">[data]</span> after lazy loading.
</wicket:fragment>

</body>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was needing! I appreciate the working example.